# Grails domain class inheritance - GORM setting the wrong foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, grails-orm, grails-2.0

GORM get confused in a very simple 3 domain classes situation: Objects - Items - Revisions. Each Item has many Revisions. As suggested by the master Mr Burt, I am not using collections here. Everything is working well until I decided to make "Item extends Object". Theses are my domain classes.

```
class Object {
  String title

  static mapping = {
    tablePerHierarchy false
    }
  }


class Item {
  String name
  Object context

  static constraints = {
    context nullable:true
    }
  }


class Revision {
  Item item
  Object context

  static constraints = {
    context nullable:true
    }
  }
```

Then in my controller:

```
def item = new Item(name:'a-name').save()
def revision = new Revision(item:item).save()
```

Simple - right? and everything works fine so far.

Plz note that *context* is null in both tables.

Now, let's make Revision extends Object, without changing anything else.

```
class Revision extends Object {
  Item item
  Object context
  static constraints = {
    context nullable:true
    }
  }
```

Compile Ok - run Ok -
BUT *context* not null anymore ! **context gets a ref to the Revision** !

What I am doing wrong ? What GORM is thinking ? Thanks for any help.

This is logSQL:

```
Hibernate: insert into item (version, context_id, name, parent_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 0
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - <null>
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - a-name
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - <null>
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - 5
Hibernate: insert into object (version, object_type, title, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 0
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - default-type
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - <null>
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - 6
Hibernate: insert into revision (context_id, item_id, id) values (?, ?, ?)
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - <null>
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 5
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [BIGINT] - 6
Hibernate: update item set version=?, context_id=?, name=?, parent_id=? where id=? and version=?
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - 1
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - 6
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - a-name
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [4] as [BIGINT] - <null>
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [5] as [BIGINT] - 5
TRACE sql.BasicBinder  - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - 0
```